# How to boot the Elementary OS 6 installer with kernel parameters?

Tags: odin, live-installation

I'd like to install Elementary OS 6 on a old MacBook Pro where I succesfully installed OS 5 in the past. The laptop has a faulty discrete graphic card that has been disabled with a special EFI tool - this requires to have `radeon.modeset=0` in the kernel parameters, otherwise boot fails with `*ERROR* UVD not responding, trying to reset the VCPU!!!`. The solution is straightforward, but I seem unable to enter the GRUB menu when booting the installer image: neither ESC nor right shift do anything. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `Shift` key after UEFI/BIOS finished loading (not 100% sure but maybe only left `Shift` works). This can be tricky to time it correctly so try few times if it doesn't work immediately. This should bring GRUB menu up.

Comment: The problem is that on a MacBook Pro one can't see when UEFI/BIOS finish loading.. There's a graphic boot menu where one can pick the boot device. I tried with both left and right shift, but so far I couldn't find the right time slot yet...